# what's the difference in below two statements for string formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, string-formatting

For any defined valriable 'e', what's the difference b/w:

`logging.info("variable is : %s" % e)` and `loggin.info("variable is : ", e)`

and when to use what?
which one will be better for UTs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one will throw an exception if you have info logging enabled, you should use `logging.info("variable is : %s", e)`, this way you only format the string if the message is going to be logged.

Comment: does it go same for loggin.error and logging.debug as well ?

Comment: Yes, they all work the same way, only difference is that the error would be thrown depending on the logging level